# UWP: How to pass a view to the InAppNotifications control?

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I am using the InAppNotifications control from the Windows Community Sample Toolkit. I have a separate usercontrol called "DemoFile.xaml" . This Demo file has the content i want to display in the InAppNotification control.

DemoFile.xaml

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBox Text = "Text"/>
  </UserControl>
```

My InAppNotifications control looks like this

Notifications.xaml

```
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
      <tk_ctl:InAppNotification
        x:Name="Notification"
        ShowDismissButton="True"
        StackMode="Replace"/>
</Grid>
```

The code behind for this Notifications.xaml.cs

```
public class Notifications : UserControl
{
   this.Notification.Show();  // want to pass the Demo File here 
}
```

How do i pass the demofile as a parameter to Show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InAppNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/inappnotification) supports to show notification using UIElement as the content of the notification. You could write it like following.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            var usercontrol = new DemoFile ();
Notification.Show(usercontrol);
        }
```